# Rename standard field on Task

Tags: tasks, activities

How to rename Call Result standard field on Task object.I don't see this field under Rename tabs and fields -> Tasks or Rename tabs and fields -->Activities.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't relabel the `Task.CallDisposition` field. I attempted to outsmart the system and use Translation Workbench to provide a "translated" label in my own language but that didn't work either. I also tried to edit the metadata via Eclipse and received a denial error there too.

It appears that your best option is to create a custom field with your desired label and add that to the page layout(s) and hide the `CallDisposition` field.

If you need the data to continue to reside in the `CallDisposition` field moving forward, you can use a workflow rule that evaluates via formula with an `ISCHANGED(yourNewField__c)` and then have a workflow field update action copy data from `yourNewField__c` to `CallDisposition` on create/edit.